# Where to get the .buildTransaction() dictionary web3 eth

Tags: python, transactions, web3py, contract

When you try to use the functions of a specific contract in web3 you should add the `.buildTransaction()` to add the dictionary of parameters of the function. for example on the documentation of web3 one should call the function and after that the `.buildTransaction()` Example: `contractFunction.buildTransaction(transaction)`. But I want to know where can I get the information that should contain this dictionary for a specific contract.

I´ve been working with the pancakeswap v2 contract,  so I was able to get all the information correct:

```
pancake_eth_contract = w3.eth.contract(address=PANCAKEROUTER_Contract, abi=getABI(PANCAKEROUTER_Contract, driver))
```

But when I try to to use the `.swapExactETHForTokens()` I also noticed that I have to provide a `.buildTransaction` method. And I have searched in the internet with a lot of answer but I want to know where can I get this information by my own. Where should I search or what parte should I read of the contract or the ABI?

```
transaction_pancake = pancake_eth_contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(amountOutMin, path_addresses, address_to, deadline).buildTransaction(buid_Trans)
```

Here Is a example that I have used and works:

```
buid_Trans = {
    'from': My_Wallet_Address,
    'value': buy_amount,
    'gas': 125000,
    'gasPrice': w3.toWei('100', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(My_Wallet_Address)
}
```

I wanna know where can I get this information by my own.

Answer (score 2):

Web3.py has some [documentation](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html?highlight=buildTransaction#web3.contract.ContractFunction.buildTransaction) about this. The `data` parameter is the relevant bit, and can contain either a ABI byte string containing the data of the function call on a contract, or in the case of a contract-creation transaction the initialisation code.

```
>>> math_contract.functions.increment(5).buildTransaction({'maxFeePerGas': 2000000000, 'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 1000000000})
{
    'to': '0x6Bc272FCFcf89C14cebFC57B8f1543F5137F97dE',
    'data': '0x7cf5dab00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005',
    'value': 0,
    'gas': 43242,
    'maxFeePerGas': 2000000000,
    'maxPriorityFeePerGas': 1000000000,
    'chainId': 1
}
```

Also web3.js has [better documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html?highlight=transaction#id62) for the equivalent function.